# What would be the best way to create a case for a product (through Asset or Contract or Product pick list or any other way)?

Tags: case, contracts, asset

I have been working to create a case for a product which would create a service order in SAP. I knew there are ways to create a case record for a product using Assets and Contracts or using the Product picklist in the case object. So that an user needs to create an asset first and add that asset while creating a case.

Are there any other best ways to create a case record for a product? What are the appropriate business scenarios to use an asset or a product pick list in a case? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The case's "asset" field is intended to represent a problem with a particular asset-- a piece of property that the company owns, rents, leases, or otherwise has in their possession or control. To use the GenWatt example, if an organization bought a generator, and it wouldn't start, a support representative would log a case against the generator's asset. This helps track the specific asset having problems, and also lets users see the history of issues against a particular asset, how many times there have been problems, etc. It also ensures that you're supporting the correct asset in cases where a RMA or RA might be involved (e.g. they have to send it in for service, they want to exchange it, a tech has to go on site, etc). Tracking assets can help determine the cost to repair versus replace, report on how much warranty repairs are costing you, etc. Since assets track serial numbers, you can also easily find where a particular asset is physically (or is supposed to be, at least), which can be useful for organizations that rent or lease assets instead of selling them.